# Resharper to load StyleCop settings

Tags: resharper, stylecop

I'm using Resharper 7.1 and StyleCop 4.7 (with Visual Studio 2012). By default Resharper loads all the StyleCop rules for inspection and for all off them the action to be taken is "Warning", even though in the Settings.StyleCop file some of the rules are disabled.

If a certain StyleCop rule is disabled I would like Resharper to "Do not show" anything (because of course, not all the default rules make sense all the time).

I know this can be done manually in the Resharper - Options - Inspection Severity, by choosing yourself what action to take for each rule. But is there a way to do this automatically? That is, make resharper not warn you about a rule being broken if it's disabled in Stylecop.Settings?

It makes sense to do this automatically, because I want to define a set of mandatory rules for all team to apply, and it would be redundant to have each engineer manually fix the action taken for each existing rule (since they are a lot).

Thanks in advance,
Mihai

Comment: So does this mean that, there is no way to import a customized .StyleCop file into ReSharper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no way to do this, although, it is possible to configure the rules manually in Resharper options and then export your options (via Manage -> Export to File) and they can be imported on other machines.